# Linux kernel NULL-pointer dereference in memset from kzalloc

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, memset, kmalloc

Quite by chance stumbled upon some code in kernel jungles and was a bit confused. There are two implementations of `kzalloc()`: in [tools/virtio/linux/kernel.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/tools/virtio/linux/kernel.h#L51) and the main one in [linux/slab.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.161/source/include/linux/slab.h#L600). Obviously, in most cases the second one is used. But sometimes the "virtio" `kzalloc()` is used.

"virtio" `kzalloc()` looks like this:

```
static inline void *kzalloc(size_t s, gfp_t gfp)
{
    void *p = kmalloc(s, gfp);

    memset(p, 0, s);
    return p;
}
```

My confusion is that "fake" `kmalloc()` used inside "tools" directory can return NULL-pointer. Also it looks like the `memset()` implementation doesn't check NULL-pointers so there could be NULL-pointer dereference.
Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Looking at the includes in `virtio/linux/kernel.h` and ` fprintf (stderr` and that it uses `malloc` and `posix_memalign` it looks like a userspace header.

Comment: And I would assume stuff inside "tools" directory would be userspace tools.

Comment: @Ivella You are right, edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that definitely looks like a bug.

The `tools/` subdirectory is a collection of user space tools (as the name suggests). You can also see this by the fact that several C standard library headers are included. So this of course is not a kernel bug (that would have been very bad), just a minor oversight in the `virtio` testing tool.

That `virtio` testing tool seems to re-define some kernel APIs to mock their behavior in userspace. That function though doesn't seem to be ever used in practice, just merely defined.

```
marco:~/git/linux/tools/virtio$ grep -r kzalloc
linux/kernel.h:static inline void *kzalloc(size_t s, gfp_t gfp)
ringtest/ptr_ring.c:static inline void *kzalloc(unsigned size, gfp_t flags)
marco:~/git/linux/tools/virtio$
```

It's probably meant to be used by someone who wishes to test some virtio kernel code in userspace.

---

In any case, you could try [reporting the bug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/reporting-bugs.html). The `get_mantainer.pl` script suggests:

```
$ perl scripts/get_maintainer.pl -f tools/virtio/linux/kernel.h
Bad divisor in main::vcs_assign: 0
"Michael S. Tsirkin" <mst@redhat.com> (maintainer:VIRTIO CORE AND NET DRIVERS)
Jason Wang <jasowang@redhat.com> (maintainer:VIRTIO CORE AND NET DRIVERS)
virtualization@lists.linux-foundation.org (open list:VIRTIO CORE AND NET DRIVERS)
linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org (open list)
```

Answer (score 3):

The header is mainly used for userspace testing, such as `virtio_test`.

From the git-log of `tools/virtio/virtio_test.c`:

> This is the userspace part of the tool: it includes a bunch of stubs for
>   linux APIs, somewhat simular to linuxsched. This makes it possible to
>   recompile the ring code in userspace.
>
> A small test example is implemented combining this with vhost_test
>   module.

So yes, the code is a bit unsafe (clean coding would test for a `NULL` pointer prior to `memset()` and bail out with an appropriate error message), but since it is just a testing tool, it seems to have been considered uncritical to skip this test.